# clock is not showing and settings are not opening

Tags: unity, upgrade, 15.10, indicator

I have upgraded my Ubuntu Linux from 14.04 to 15.10 and after that the clock is not showing in top unity bar and even the **System Settings...** is not opening as well.

I have used `killall unity-panel-service` this command to reset *unity-panel-service* but this didn't work.

Also for resolving clock issue followed solutions posted on form like reinstalling `clock indicator` as:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-datetime
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```

But this commands gives an error:

> E: Package 'indicator-datetime' has no installation candidate

Any help to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 is EOL and is not supported.  You will not be able to install the missing indicator application.  Please consider installing a supported version of Ubuntu like 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, 17.04 (which is about to go EOL) or 17.10.  Please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases